# MVC C# List Email with a mailto: {variable} from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper

I have a view page where I am listing a username and their email address from the database and I was wondering how to display the email so when it is clicked on it opens up the outlook mailbox and sends and email to that address:

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Comtrex_ICU.Models.UserProfile>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserTable";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2 class="admin-home-link orange-titles">@Html.ActionLink("User Information", "AdminIndex")</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) | @Html.ActionLink("<a href=mailto:"(modelItem => item.Email)">(modelItem => item.Email)</a>")</p>


}
```

Anyone know the proper syntax?

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto) out.

Comment: This would be for a static page, I'm looking to send by using emails populated by a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing your `<a>` tag into `Html.ActionLink` as a parameter which is not something that it expects to receive. Instead, you can omit the `Html.ActionLink` entirely and just build the `<a>` tag as follows:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) | <a href="@string.Format("mailto:{0}", item.Email)">@item.Email</a></p>
```

note that `Html.ActionLink` will generate the entire `<a>` tag for you and is used when you'd like to generate a link that will hit an action on one of your controllers so that doesn't really fit with what you're trying to do and is why it isn't needed.

Comment: This works but displays the email as (modelItem => item.Email). When I click it it does go to the proper email

Comment: check my updated/edited answer, at first I didn't notice there was an issue with the text for the link you were displaying

Comment: <a href="@string.Format("mailto:{0}", item.Email)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</a></p> not sure if what you edited works but this works too. Thanks so much for your help